# How to get same instance within a page request using structure map in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I want to get same instance within a page request/
Can I use HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped() method for this?
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped`, but using the `HttpContextLifecycle` would be a more intuitive:

```
container.Configure(r => r
    .For<IRepository>()
    .Use<SqlRepository>()
    .LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle());
```

Comment: what about if httpcontext not available?                              I am using class for non web requests also.

Comment: Yes, in that case `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` would be your friend ;-)

Comment: How do i check created instance is within scope of httpcontext?

Comment: From the application's perspective, this shouldn't matter. If you need to check this inside your application, you should rethink your application design or the choosen registration.

Comment: in class itself, which i have created object.whether it's using httpcontext or ThreadLocalScope

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Which application logic is dependent on this?

Comment: to know query count of page, so if it is using httpcontext then i will increase the count.

Comment: If you update your question with the code of what you're doing, I might be able to supply you with alternative solutions.